# Change Shapefile data source encoding?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, encoding

I tried to change the only the shapefile datasource encoding through properties and also [How to encode shapefiles from LATIN1 to UTF-8?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15912) but it doesn't change it.

Without saving the QGIS project can't I directly change the shapefile datasource encoding?

I also tried this code, it shows change encoding but as I open the shapefile again it show the same old system encoding:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.setProviderEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    layer.dataProvider().setEncoding(u'UTF-8')
    print layer.name(), layer.dataProvider().encoding()
```

*(I am not saving QGIS project, just accessing and saving shapefile directly. When **I save the project and do this task then it work correctly**)*

Comment: You can take a look at the code in the plugin: shapefile_encoding_fixer

Comment: can i save in shapefile through qgis without saving the project?

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking your layer and using the `Save As...` option?

Comment: @Joseph yes man off course, i already mention that answer in my post! I direct open shape file into qgis project and change its encoding through save as but as i open it again it remaing to system (unchanged).

Comment: @Joseph i did not save qgis project, when i save qgis project and open shape file through it then it works correctly!

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - Ahh, sometimes when someone posts a link which contains answers, they don't try all of them ;). The `Save As...` option works for me, which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: @Joseph 2.18.0 version i am using, could you please tell me the steps you performed! I did it through 1. drop shape file in qgis 2.. save as new shape file with utf 8. 3. open that new file and found same system encoding

Comment: @Joseph i didn't save qgis project

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - Using the exact same QGIS version on Windows 7 64-bit with the exact same steps you mentioned. Works for me...

Comment: First, you need to set the correct encoding in the layer  properties (the attribute table fields' vales should look good). Then, you can use save as... and choose that, or any other, encoding for the output.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto what does it mean " fields' vales should look good. "?

Comment: I mean your data values must not show strange characters.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto ok i have understand and but problem still persist. are you saving the project also?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: @AlexandreNeto its simple text and integer data! let me know the steps you have perform to do this task in Answer section. May your task help to do this.

Comment: @Joseph i did it so many times! can you explain your steps. maybe something is missing by me. Are you saving the project also? I am not saving the project! as i mentioned so many time in this chat and question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the menubar, go to:

```
Settings > Options > Data Sources > Data source handling
```

and uncheck the *Ignore shapefile encoding declaration* setting:

[image: Encoding setting]

This sets all layers loaded into QGIS to be default encoded to `UTF-8`

Comment: Thanks @Joseph additionally for future user this link also helpful https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13203. Actually Ignore shapefile encoding declaration checked option ignore the utf-8 settings. its ignore .cpg file.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan - Most welcome and thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 7):

To recapitulate the different location where you can set the encoding:

**When you open a shapefile:**
[image: Open shp as]

**When you open a CSV:**
[image: Add CSV]

**When you save a vector file:**
[image: Save vector file as]

**In the layer properties:**
[image: Layer properties]

And, as mentioned by @Joseph, you should probably uncheck the Ignore shapefile encoding declaration setting.

Comment: Thanks victor your last line help me a lot. https://hub.qgis.org/issues/13203

Answer (score 4):

When you use `Save As ...`, you have to select a different filename, and `Add file to canvas`.

As a consequence, you **MUST** save the project too to get the new shapefile in it. The unsaved project still includes the untouched shapefile, and the wrong encoding.

BTW the `Data encoding` in the Layer properties is part of the project file, not the shapefile. Your code example does not write anything inside the shapefile, it changes just the layer settings of the project.