# Is it possible to change default encoding for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, windows, linux, encoding

I often transfer layers from Windows machine to Linux and vice versa and it causes me problems (incorrectly displayed labels and same with text in attribute table) when I use drag and drop to put vector layers in QGIS.

On linux there is System encoding set to UTF-8 while on Windows it is Windows-1250. Is it possible to change the setting of the Windows version of QGIS to be also set to UTF-8 by default?

Tried to google a solution but no success.

Comment: This may be related: [How to change Shapefile data source encoding?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219092/how-to-change-shapefile-data-source-encoding), answered by Joseph. This may not change the default setting to UTF-8, but it should honor UTF-8 if layers are transferred from Linux.

Answer (score 8):

Go to the "Settings -> Options -> Data Sources" menu, 
and look for the checkbox "Ignore shapefile encoding declaration",
 when you uncheck it, the default encoding (for shapefiles) will be 'set to' UTF8. 
This will actually prevent ogr's 'on the fly' conversion of shapefiles encoding.
See [this thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Shapefiles-default-encoding-td5300702.html) for further details.

[image: Data Sources Menu]