# Source encoding of Argentinean words that contain accents, "ñ", and end in "-ción"

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, encoding, spanish

I've trying to find the right source encoding that allows me to read correctly my attributes table with words that contain accents, "ñ, ü" and end in -"ción", but I still could not find the correct encoding. I've tried with "System", UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, iso-8869-15, iso-8859-1, Windows-1252 and Windows-1250 and none worked I still see symbols in the spaces where there has to be an accent or a Ñ, ü or the termination "-ción". I am using QGIS 3.24.

I leave an image of what it appears to me in the attributes table. For example instead of saying Constitución appears  ConstituciÃƒÂ³n; en vez de decir Desagües it appears DesagÃƒÂŒes:
[image: For example instead of saying Constitución appears ConstituciÃƒÂ³n; en vez de decir Desagües it appears DesagÃƒÂŒes]

Comment: You need to look at the actual bytes used to encode the characters, something we can't do at this remove. And, unfortunately, there's no reason to believe the same encoding was used in all strings, so you might need to create a decision tree in code to recode it all as UTF-16 or UTF-8.

Comment: You need to set your codepage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/locales-and-code-pages?view=msvc-170 to the same as the text https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238182/is-it-possible-to-change-default-encoding-for-qgis, as for what codepage you need I can't help - I don't have a knack for languages that aren't scripting or programming languages, so I'm limited to English only.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers