# Display Emoji Characters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, encoding, emoji

I have data with emoji characters in a field that in ArcMap are shown as emojis in the Attribute Table.

I've tried all the usual encoding suspects in QGIS but haven't managed to get them display correctly.

Does anyone know if and how it can be achieved in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219092/how-to-change-shapefile-data-source-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying and fiddling with datasource encoding, both in QGIS and externally for the attribute table, I couldn't get it to work.

Then I tried opening it in QGIS 3 and it does show the emoji characters.

QGIS 2.99 on left, QGIS 2.18.11 on right.

[image]