# Converted Mapinfo file (originally in Chinese) to SHP but the attributes are jumbled/wrong

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo, arcgis-10.6, chinese

I converted a set of MapInfo files to SHP using [org2gui](http://ogr2gui.ca/). Unfortunately, the attributes got jumbled. The original dataset was in Chinese, so that is probably contributing to the jumbling. Screenshot below shows jumbles.

I uploaded the source Mapinfo files to filebin [here](https://filebin.net/f6kkk2hjx0quf86b), and I uploaded the converted SHP to filebin [here](https://filebin.net/jcenrgpo9pt9gfga).

Is there anyway to recover the jumbled attributes? I have opened SHP in ArcGIS with Chinese characters in the attributes before, so it's not solely a language character rendering issue.

[image]

Comment: It's a codepage problem, Chinese is a multibyte character system but how the multibytes are converted into characters depend on your codepage. Being monolingual in English I can't help much but I think you need codepage 936 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936_(Microsoft_Windows). Can I suggest you get QGIS and open the MapInfo file in that and experiment with your codepage https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219092/change-shapefile-data-source-encoding until you understand the characters then use save as to export to shape.

Comment: Also another good link here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013192 but it requires registry hacks which would *really* upset your I.T. support team.

Comment: @MichaelStimson wow, it worked!! (the first comment, not the formidable registry hacks, haha). I followed Victor's answer here (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219092/change-shapefile-data-source-encoding), setting the encoding to Windows-936 as you noted. Thanks so much for your help! If you want to move your comments into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Considering this is a duplicate of another post the best thing to do is mark it as a duplicate and upvote the answer that worked for you.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Upvoted @Victor on the duplicate page