# Attributes encoding problem with rgdal::writeOGR

Tags: shapefile, r, qgis-3, rgdal, encode

I performed an intersection of two SpatialPolygonsDataFrame on R (3.5.1) using `raster::intersect`. 
Here's the structure of the resulting SPDF attributes table

```
> str(shp@data)
'data.frame':   944 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ COD5      : chr  "1122" "1122" "1122" "1122" ...
 $ LIV_1     : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ LIV_2     : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ LIV_3     : chr  "2" "2" "2" "2" ...
 $ LIV_4     : chr  "2" "2" "2" "2" ...
 $ LIV_5     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ SHAPE_AREA: num  23499 10474 5227 13752 71721 ...
```

[image]

I exported the SPDF with `rgdal::writeOGR`

```
writeOGR(shp, 'C:/foo', 'shp', 'ESRI Shapefile', overwrite_layer=T)
```

but QGIS 3.4 LTR was unable to display attributes correctly

[image]

Is it an enconding problem with `rgdal::writeOGR`? I read the documentation of the function but I didn't figure out how to solve it. 
I tried with

```
writeOGR(shp, 'C:/foo', 'shp', 'ESRI Shapefile', layer_options="ENCODING=UTF-8", overwrite_layer=T)
```

but the result didn't change. I also tried with the updated `rgdal` package version (1.4-4).

Comment: are you sure that you're passing the encoding to writeOGR as intended?
Usage

writeOGR(obj, dsn, layer, driver, dataset_options = NULL,
 layer_options=NULL, verbose = FALSE, check_exists=NULL,
 overwrite_layer=FALSE, delete_dsn=FALSE, morphToESRI=NULL,
 encoding=NULL)
see: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgdal/versions/1.4-4/topics/writeOGR

Comment: Can you use another output format? I know some people are restricted to use what is locally mandated, but if you can at least try something like a "Geopackage" and that works then you might have a good argument for change.

Comment: Possibly related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219092/change-shapefile-data-source-encoding

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman, the solution described in the post you suggested works actually. It is an issue of QGIS rather than R then.