# Where is "Ignore shapefile encoding declaration" placed in QGIS 3.10.7?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, encoding

When I tried to change data source encoding of a DXF file in QGIS, the field is grayed out and stuck to UTF-8.

Then I found this [solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219092/change-shapefile-data-source-encoding/219137#219137). But there's no `Ignore shapefile encoding declaration` checkbox in the place described.

How should I find this option in version 3.10.7?

Comment: Best way to set the encoding is when you are initially opening the file are you able to set it there? Also 3.10 is a very old version. I would upgrade to 3.16 which is the stable version of QGIS.